# Getting current semester in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, between

I'm having a trouble on this `query` it says `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BETWEEN'` but when I tried to individually execute the `BETWEEN` conditions without `CASE WHEN` it runs normally, Also in relation to the Title is their a proper way to get the semester in SQL SERVER?

```
DECLARE @ActiveSemester INT

SET @ActiveSemester = ISNULL((SELECT [value]
FROM spms_tblProfileDefaults WHERE eid = 7078 and ps_id = 1), (SELECT [value] 
FROM spms_configs WHERE actions = 'semester_active') )

SELECT FORMAT((SUM((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, a.actual_start_time, a.actual_end_time) 
- isnull(datediff(minute, break_start, break_end), 0))/ 60.0)), '0.00')
FROM spms_tblSubTask as a
LEFT JOIN pmis.dbo.employee as b ON a.eid = b.eid
LEFT JOIN pmis.dbo.time_reference as c ON c.code = ISNULL(b.TimeReference, 'TIME14')
LEFT JOIN dbo.spms_vwOrganizationalChart as e ON a.eid = e.eid
cross apply
 (
        select  break_start = case  when c.break_from between a.actual_start_time and a.actual_end_time
                    then c.break_from
                    when a.actual_start_time between c.break_from and c.break_to
                    then a.actual_start_time
                    else NULL
                    end,
                break_end  = case   when c.break_to between a.actual_start_time and a.actual_end_time
                    then c.break_to
                    when a.actual_end_time between c.break_from and c.break_to
                    then a.actual_end_time
                    end
) as d
WHERE
b.Shift = 0 and a.eid = 7078 and
YEAR(a.start_date_time) = YEAR(GETDATE()) and a.action_code = 1 
and 
(CASE 
WHEN 
@ActiveSemester = 1
THEN 
a.start_date_time BETWEEN CAST(CONCAT('01/01/',YEAR(GETDATE())) as date) AND     
CAST(CONCAT('06/30/',YEAR(GETDATE())) as date)
ELSE 
a.start_date_time BETWEEN CAST(CONCAT('07/01/',YEAR(GETDATE())) as date) AND     
CAST(CONCAT('12/31/',YEAR(GETDATE())) as date)
END)
```

Comment: You can replace the `CASE` statement in the `WHERE` clause with the following line: 
`(@ActiveSemester = 1 AND a.start_date_time BETWEEN CAST(CONCAT('01/01/',YEAR(GETDATE())) as date) AND   CAST(CONCAT('06/30/',YEAR(GETDATE()))))`

Comment: For some reason, people leap towards using `CASE` in SQL when in fact they just need to use simple boolean operators. `CASE` is an *expression*. It returns a scalar *value* (per row). It's not some form of control flow that can somehow be embedded inside other statements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `@ActiveSemester` can take on the values 0 or 1, I'd just write this as:

```
WHERE
b.Shift = 0 and a.eid = 7078 and
YEAR(a.start_date_time) = YEAR(GETDATE()) and a.action_code = 1 
and 
@ActiveSemester = ((MONTH(a.start_date_time)-1)/6)
```

Now, it's worth noting that this expression cannot use an index on `start_date_time` to satisfy this final predicate. **If** that's an issue, and the query isn't performing well, then I'd either recommend persisted computed columns in this table to extract the year and month value from the `start_date_time` column, modify the above query to use those columns and add appropriate indexes, *or* to populate a calendar table which has such values (and semester) properly represented and *join* to that table above, to again simplify the expressions and allow indexes to be used.

---

Note, also, that the column name worries me. If it *does* contain a time portion as well as a date, then note that the expressions in your original query would have excluded any values that occurred *after* midnight on 30th June and 31st December<sup>1</sup>. I presume that wasn't your intent and the query above doesn't suffer this same shortcoming.

<sup>1</sup>Because `2018-06-30T00:01:00` is strictly later than `2018-06-30T00:00:00` (which is what `CAST(CONCAT('06/30/',YEAR(GETDATE())) as date)` expands out to) and so isn't `BETWEEN` the start and end dates you gave.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the other answer was Deleted and here's what I did as the other points out about the proper use of CASE WHEN

```
WHERE
'other condition' and
a.start_date_time BETWEEN 
(CASE 
WHEN @ActiveSemester = '1'
THEN
CAST(CONCAT('01/01/',YEAR(GETDATE())) as date)
ELSE
CAST(CONCAT('07/01/',YEAR(GETDATE())) as date)
END)
AND 
(CASE 
WHEN @ActiveSemester = '1'
THEN
CAST(CONCAT('06/30/',YEAR(GETDATE())) as date)
ELSE
CAST(CONCAT('12/31/',YEAR(GETDATE())) as date)
END)
```

with this, I get the results I wanted. Thanks